# The urn problem - taking balls out

Tags: probability

I have a problem. From an urn with $x$ white and $y$ black balls, we take $k$ white and $l$ black balls. What is the probability that the next ball taken out is white? We do not put the balls back in the urn once they are taken out. I thought the answer is $\frac{k}{k+l}$, but someone told me that's not true. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: How many white balls remain in the urn? How many balls remain total?

Comment: As stated, it sounds like you are simply removing $k$ white and $\ell$ black balls, so you are asking for the probability of picking out one white ball from an urn with $x-k$ white balls and $y-\ell$ black balls.

Answer (score 1):

If x/(x+y) is the probability of choosing a white ball from an untouched urn, and y/(x+y) is the probability of choosing a black ball from an untouched urn, then by taking black and white balls out, the probability of choosing a white ball can increase/decrease to (x-k)/((x-k)+(y-l)) and similarly the probability of choosing a black ball is (y-l)/((x-k)+(y-l)).

Answer (score 0):

Probability: (Number of desired outcome) / (Number of all possible outcome)

In this case: (Number of white balls) / (Number of balls)

Number of white balls remaining: x-k

Number of balls remaining: (x-k) + (y-l)

Therefore, probability that the next ball is white = (x-k)/((x-k) + (y-l))